# Triple to double chain ring

Tags: gears

I have a defy 3 with a triple chain ring I would like to change it to a double can it be done and what will I need?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  To get the best possible answer it would be good if you can give us more information about your bike (e.g. year) and what components (crank, derailleur, etc.) it is currently equipped with.

Comment: Note that the Defy 3 was made with a FSA triple crank only from 2009 to 2011; from 2012 on (until it was retired in 2016) it switched to a compact double (34/50).

Comment: Along with DavidWs comment - knowing what problem you are trying to fix/goal you hope to achieve with a double will help us to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: A month later - I'm tempted to close as "needs more detail"   Please provide more detail about what you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You will need at a minimum a double or compact double chainset compatable with your bottom bracket (or chainset with suitable bottom bracket) and a double front derailleur that matches the frame and is suitable for the number of rear sprockets (8/9/10).

Ideally you will also change the left hand shifter so you can benefit from the trim positions.

There are more specifics but without knowing what your current gruppo is, they aren't yet worth expanding on.

Comment: Could OP just remove the large outer ring? It will move his chainline in a bit but no different to just using the middle or inner ring. Unless OP wants completely different gearing but he hasn’t specified why he wants a double

Comment: Don’t you mean crankset (i.e. cranks+chainrings), not chainset?

Comment: @Michael "chainset" is UK English for "crankset."

Answer (score 1):

I have done that on a "trekking triple". It has a "trekking triple" front derailleur for triples where the big ring is about 48 teeth in size.

The way to do it is to simply remove the smallest chainring. So previously I had 26/36/48 crankset. Not foreseeing any use for the ridiculous 26T ring, I modified it to be a 36/48 crankset.

The front shifter is a friction bar-end shifter so it is compatible with anything.

However, this is not completely ideal:

- The chainline will not be ideal
- The front derailleur that is designed for triples may not have enough range in the low limit adjusting screw. Putting in a longer screw could help but even in that case I have noticed the long screw interferes with the front derailleur operation in some settings and I can only barely limit it to such a position that the chain doesn't drop from the previously-middle now-small ring.

The reason I did that and don't use a "road double" crankset instead is that a "road" crankset requires a "road" bottom bracket that has no spacers. Thus, I cannot use a chainguard that attaches with a ring-style attachment between the Hollowtech II bottom bracket and the frame. By using an "MTB" bottom bracket (that is compatible with "MTB" and "trekking" cranksets), there are spacers and I can remove one of the spacers and replace it with the chainguard mount.

Also "road" cranksets have at least a 50-tooth big ring usually and the chainguards that I use are designed for 48-tooth rings max, so even if a "road" bottom bracket allowed installation of a chainguard, the big ring would need to be changed.